# How to write update Query in CriteriaUpdate using joins?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I trying to write code regarding CriteriaUpdate using joins.
but, in CriteriaUpdate joins are not working.
Then I tried using subqueries like below ..,

```
CriteriaBuilder userBuilder = deviceSession.getCriteriaBuilder();
                    CriteriaUpdate<Switch> deviceUpdate = userBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(Switch.class);
                    Root<Switch> deviceUpdateRoot = deviceUpdate.from(Switch.class);
                    
                    Subquery<Switch> deviceSubquery = deviceUpdate.subquery(Switch.class);
                    Root<Switch> roomRoot = deviceSubquery.from(Switch.class);
                    Join<Switch, Rooms> join = roomRoot.join("room" ,JoinType.LEFT);
                    
                    deviceUpdate.set(deviceUpdateRoot.get("displayName"),"SSS");
                    deviceUpdate.set(deviceUpdateRoot.get("device"),"device");
                    deviceUpdate.set(deviceUpdateRoot.get("operation"),"operation");
                    ***deviceUpdate.set(join.get("roomId"),device.getRoomId());***
                    deviceUpdate.where(userBuilder.equal(deviceUpdateRoot.get("deviceName"),device.getDeviceName()));
                    int returnValue = deviceSession.createQuery(deviceUpdate).executeUpdate();
```

but I am getting error like **org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.roomId'**
can you please help from this isuue.

Comment: Hi! As far as I know, you can't update multiple tables in one statement. And I'm not talking about JPA, but SQL itself.

Comment: I would suggest you to build this update query as SQL and try to run it in your DB to check whether it works.